# ContentResolver query database view not database table

Tags: java, android, sql

I use a ContentResolver to get data from a table name 'story' and the uri is `content://com.apptest.data/story` but I dont understand why the cursor always get data from a view of 'story' not table 'story'.

Anyone can help me? thank you

Update : my query is

```
String[] projection = { //this is 4 static column name
            STORY_ID,
            STORY_COVER_URI,
            STORY_FILE_PATH,
            STORY_COVER_RECT_RATIO,
    };

    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.apptest.data/story"),
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null);
```

But I think problem not in my query, is in the contentprovider because when I have wrong syntax it catch exception said that I'm call story_view view not story table

`SELECT story_id, cover, coverRectRatio FROM story_view`

Comment: your `ContentProvider#query()` method is wrong

Comment: post your `ContentProvider#query()` method

Comment: below is my query, I think problem not in my query because when I have wrong syntax it throw exception "SELECT story_id, cover, coverRectRatio FROM story_view "

Comment: what's the stack trace?

Comment: I add a wrong syntax and the log say : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: aaa (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT story_id, cover, coverRectRatio FROM story_view WHERE aaa                                                                         Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)                                                                        Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                  (no such column: aaa (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT story_id, cover, coverRectRatio FROM story_view WHERE aaa)

Comment: whats unclear in `"no such column: aaa "`? post your full `ContentProvider#query()` method

Comment: In wrong syntax case I code "String where = "aaa";
  Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.apptest.data/story"),
                projection,
                where,
                null,
                null);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContentProvider` that provides your `cursor` may have different logic. It may also do additional stuff on your request before returning the result to you. In this case, it queries the "view" instead of table.

Comment: yes, when I log the query it call "SELECT story_id, cover, coverRectRatio FROM story_view WHERE GROUP BY story_id" , I dont understand why it call FROM story_view but the uri is "content://com.apptest.data/story"

Comment: @moviehay0032 the uri does not necesarily mean it gets it from "story" table